# Rxjs Angular 2 async pipe working once

Tags: angular, rxjs

I tried to do an async pipe on my project, but this is really working just the first time.

After my http.get returns nothing at all... 
So I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong, because now I'm completely stuck.

(I do not have a JSONP web service available and I think it's here that I have a pb but normally this would be the same)

My service code :

```
getLocation(query: string): Observable<Array<Prediction>> {
    console.log("[call getLocation]")
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.locationUrl = this.locationUrl+"?location="+query;
    headers.append("Accept","application/json");
    return this.http.get(this.locationUrl, {headers: headers})
        .switchMap(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My component code :

```
predictions: Observable<Array<Prediction>>;


constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _EventCreationService: EventCreationService,
    private _LocationService: LocationService) {

    console.log("[constrct]")
    predictions = this.term.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((term:string): Observable<Array<Prediction>> => {
            console.log("[changed called]"+term)
            return this._LocationService.getLocation(term)
        })
    );
}
```

and simply have this in my HTML to get the data :

```
*ngFor="#item of predictions |async"
```

So i think it's my location service that is not un-subscribing from the first event, but that is why I was using switchmap... but it seems that is not working.

edit : 
her is the code of extractData and handleError :

```
 private extractData(res: Response): Array<Prediction> {
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
        throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    let body = res.json();
    let result : Array<Prediction> = new Array<Prediction>();
    result.push(body.predictions);
    console.log("-->"+JSON.stringify(body))
    return result;
}

private handleError (error: any) {
   // In a real world app, we might send the error to remote logging infrastructure
   let errMsg = error || 'Server error';
   console.error(JSON.stringify(errMsg)); // log to console instead
   return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

i'm starting of wondering if it could be a possible error of my angular 2 or rxjs version ....

Answer (score 1):

I see an error in your `getLocation` method. It's not the `switchMap` operator but the `map` one:

```
getLocation(query: string): Observable<Array<Prediction>> {
  (...)
  return this.http.get(this.locationUrl, {headers: headers})
    .map(this.extractData) // <-----------
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: why use map ? i've used switchmap to automatically unsubscribe to last event.

Comment: Yes agreed but in this particular case, it seems that you want to extract data not unsubscribe the last event. In the service code... Or there is a typo in your question. See: `.switchMap(this.extractData)`

Comment: ok just tryed with map, but same result. first time i got the result, after the http.get is not working and i get an empty result.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean by `http.get is not working`? Do you have a particular error?

Comment: My web services works fine, this is not the error. Here we see that the first time this returns result for "Par" then when i change this is not working anymore, my http.get returns an empty array.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/kQrNEj2hw7uoWA2CjHdY?p=preview. Could you add the content of the `extractData` and `handleError` methods?

Comment: Wow great work, thank you. I edited my post, as i've said i'm starting to ask myself if it'snt a bug of htt.get of angular 2 in beta 15...

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps. Agreed that you could make a test with later versions ;-)

Comment: yes will give a try and tell you. Thank you again, at least i've learned some usefull trick with rxJs ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `switchMap` use `flatMap` which projects each element of an observable sequence to another observable sequence.

Incas you want to cancel previous observables if they are in progress, use `flatMapLatest`

Comment: after searching, it seems that : In RxJS 5, flatMapLatest has been renamed to switchMap. So ??

Comment: @McflyDroid owh! Been a sec on that. Thanks. Let me try on my end again and then will advise